# HTTP File upload (multipart/form-data) on Android 4.1.2 always times out to any server

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, multipartform-data

We're finding all regular HTTP POST file uploads on Android 4.1.2 are timing out, with both the stock browser and Chrome. We've confirmed this on multiple websites: We're debugging [capn.me](http://capn.me/) but it also happens on [imgur](http://imgur.com). When inspecting the page's Network tab, the request can be seen but is (pending) until timeout (20s on our server, seemingly never on imgur).

Our test browser UA is "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; Nexus 7 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166  Safari/535.19", on a Nexus tablet but it happens on Nexus phone too. Lots of googling hasn't shown anyone else having this issue, but to us it seems like a confirmed bug. Is anyone able to shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately we never found a solution for this, only multiple but scattered reports of people reproducing the issue. Therefore I'm going to close this issue as it appears fixed in the later versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have an answer for you. We're experiencing a similar issue posting  multipart/form-data.
It works as long as the file is very small.  A 43 byte gif works for us while a 1000 byte text file fails.
Our UA is:
Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:16.0) Gecko/16.0 Firefox/16.0